# System aggregation using virtualization

Tags: operating-system, virtualization

Instead of virtualizing a single machine to appear as several machines it is theoretically possible to make several machines appear as one.  [ScaleMP](http://www.scalemp.com) Appears to use this technique.

Where can I find research/literature about development such a system?
Are there any open source platforms for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a system which does this transparently, i.e. which pretends that multiple computers are one.

If programs need to run on multiple computers they are often specifically developed for that purpose, often using a technique such as [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface).

Also, systems with a lot of running processes may take a running process and [move](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_migration) it to another computer, to distribute load more evenly.